# Self-hosted build server for Flutter(iOS)

Tags: flutter, azure-pipelines, devops, bitrise

I'm currently doing cicd with Bitrise, but I'm thinking of switching to self-hosted with mac mini.
I can only think of a way to use fastlane with azure pipelines, but if you have any other ideas, please tell me. The requirement is to trigger a push to github to start the build and upload it to firebase appdistribution.

Comment: Hi, Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

> Trigger a push to GitHub to start the build

Create build pipeline and select GitHub as the source, select the tab Triggers and enable the option Enable continuous integration to configure [CI build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#ci-triggers).

> upload it to firebase appdistribution.

Please refer to this doc to [deploy to Firebase from Azure DevOps](https://medium.com/@dneimke/deploy-to-firebase-from-vsts-3b58430b6379)